# Run "sudo chef-client" from workstation

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to figure out a way by which I can run "sudo chef-client" from my workstation. I tried following way but failed.

> C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo>knife ssh name:node1 -a hostname  -x windows -i knife.pem "sudo chef-client"
>
> > FATAL: 1 node found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute.”

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Your node doesn't have a `hostname` attribute set. Try `-a ipaddress` instead to use the default IP address on the machine.

For posterity, based on comments below the user was unclear that Windows hosts don't generally run SSH daemons and thus `knife ssh` cannot be used. `knife winrm` is the recommended option for Windows nodes.

Comment: Hi
I tried following. Still no luck. I kept the IP address of Chef-server in place of hostname.

C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo>knife ssh name:node1 -a 10.106.a.b -x windows -i knife.pem "sudo chef-client"
FATAL: 1 node found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the c
onnection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribut
e.

Comment: No I mean literally `-a ipaddress`. The `-a` argument is the attribute name used to look up the connection details in the search results.

Comment: This is what I got.
>C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo>knife ssh name:node1 -a ipaddress -x windows -i
>chef-validator.pem "sudo chef-client"
WARNING: Failed to connect to 10.106.69.76 -- Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection
 could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)

Comment: You seem to be using Windows, is the target also a Windows machine? If so, it is unlikely to be running an SSH daemon. Make sure you can SSH normally using a standalone client and once that works, knife ssh should too.

Comment: My Chef-server is a red-hat server. Workstation is a windows machine. Should it be changed to something else?

Comment: What about the node you are trying to connect to? That error means you can't connect to port 22 so either a firewall is in the way or there isn't an SSH daemon running.

Comment: Node1 is a windows machine. Firewall is off. How can I check about SSH daemon?

Comment: Unless you did something really weird, SSH is not a windows thing. You'll want to use the `knife winrm` commands and plugin.

Comment: I have already tried winrm, then I thought since the server is a red hat server, winrm is not working. When I tried using winrm command, I got following output:

C:\Users\Administrator\chef-repo>knife winrm name:node1 -a ipaddress -x windows
-i chef-validator.pem "sudo chef-client"
ERROR: LoadError: Could not open library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MIT\Kerberos\bi
n\gssapi32.dll': The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Installing and configuring WinRM is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Definitely it isn't. I have already installed and configured winrm. I want to know whether the format of this command is correct or I need some correction?

Comment: Yes I suspect that is incorrect. `-x windows` looks suspect unless you really have an user named `"windows"`. The `-i` argument is entirely incorrect on several levels and overall this is beyond the scope of something that can be answered on SO.